# Stored date time is before or after the current date? using java -Joda Time

Tags: java, datetime, logic, jodatime

**Requirement:** Working on webinar meetings where a user can schedule a meeting by filling a form. The form contains a topic, description, list of members, meeting start time, and date. These details are stored in a table. After scheduling a meeting user can view his **upcoming** and **previous** meetings.

Dates are stored in this format **2021-02-22** using DATE datatype.
Start time: **12:48:00** in this format.

need to find whether the meeting date is yet commencing or it's a previous meeting?

```
public WebinarEntity getScheduledMeeting(int CompanyID){
Date currentDate=new Date(); //Todays Date.
//get the stored data. 
DAO_Factory dao=new DAOImpl();
Date storedDate=dao.getMeetingDate(CompanyID);

if(currentDate.before(storedDate)
{
  //display the meeting details as previous

}
else {
      //display the meeting details as upcoming!
}
return new WebinarEntity(Details of previous or upcoming);
```

How to code to find the stored data is upcoming or previous based on Date and time?

**Issue in above code:** say for example our meeting scheduled on **22-2-2021** at **4:00 pm** this meeting details are shown in the **previous meeting column** rather it should be shown/displayed in the **upcoming**.
**EDIT**: **CurrentDate-2021-02-22 08:00am**
**Stored Date-2021-02-22 04:00pm**

Comment: sorry I dont understand what you are having a problem with?What you need? Could you show us how your table+data look like?

Are you actually having a problem in retrieving data from a specific column?
Or?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Your description of the "Issue in above code" makes no sense unless you tell us what `currentDate` is.

Comment: @tgdavies please check the dates now

Comment: CurrentDate-2021-02-22 08:00am is before Stored Date-2021-02-22 04:00pm, so the condition in your if statement is true. From the `java.util.Date javadoc`: "true if and only if the instant of time represented by this Date object is strictly earlier than the instant represented by when"

Comment: Date and Time are stored in two different columns @tgdavies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use either of the terrible `Date` classes. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

You tagged for the Joda-Time project. But you do not see to be using it. That project is  now in maintenance mode, also supplanted by *java.time*.

Your Question ignores the crucial issue of time zone.

Book appointments using `LocalDateTime` and `ZoneId`, storing each of those in a pair of columns in your database. The SQL-standard types will be `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` and `VARCHAR` respectively. You may also want to store the duration of the meeting as text using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format.

At runtime, when you need to build out a schedule, combine the two to get a `ZonedDateTime`. This class represents a moment, and you can compare to the current moment to determine if it is past or future. To get the end of the meeting make a `Duration` object of your ISO 8601 string, and add to your `ZonedDateTime` start.

This has been addressed many many times already on Stack Overflow. I myself, and others, have written on this topic in much detail. So search to learn more.

> CurrentDate-2021-02-22 08:00am
> Stored Date-2021-02-22 04:00pm

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( 2021 , 2 , 22 , 8 , 0 ) ;  // Stored as TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE in database.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;                     // Stored as text in database, in `Continent/Region` format.
ZonedDateTime start = ldt.atZone( z ) ;                          // Dynamically calculated, not stored.
Duration duration = Duration.parse( "PT1H30M" ) ;                // Stored in database as text, in standard ISO 8601 format `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`.
ZonedDateTime end = start.plus( duration ) ;                     // Dynamically calculated, not stored.

ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
boolean isFuture = start.isAfter( now ) ;
Duration untilThen = Duration.between( now , start ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my issue.